# Error: Path Must Include project and resource name:/<jar file name> in eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I am adding an external jar file to my Web server Application based on Java Servlets in Eclipse IDE. But when i tried to add that jar file an error occured as `"An internal error occurred during updating tag library index . Path Must Include project and resource name:/<jar file name>".` Please let me know which path the application asks or there is any specific directory where i have to put that jar file or any file where i have to update the location of jar file.
Thanks

Comment: In which directory u try to add jar file ..? or where u try to place java file ...?

Comment: I added the jar file in web-inf/lib/ directory but the problem is same

Comment: Have you checked if there are any .TLD files into the WEB-INF directory, or packaged in the /META-INF/tags of your JAR files? It sounds to me as if some or that .TLD files is missing the path node (within a taglib/tagfile node).

Comment: In the case where your JAR is being produced by a project in the application's Deployment Assembly, make sure that project is correctly building and has the correct output folder.

Answer (score 0):

JARs should go into your `/WEB-INF/lib` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to add external jar

1.Right click on your `project`

2.Click on the `Properties`

3.Click on `Java Build Path`

4.Go to `Libraries` Tab and click on the `Add External Jar` button

5.Select the jar file from your local directory

6.Press `OK` button

Comment: This is the wrong answer for servlet applications. This way it would only end up in compiletime classpath and not in runtime classpath (and thus still cause runtime class not found exceptions). You basically need to add the JAR in *Deployment Assembly* property instead of the *Build Path* property. However, just dropping straight in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder is much easier.